# java.lang.VerifyError/Stack underflow error at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifiyImpl

Tags: java, struts, websphere-8, java-6

I am trying to upgrade a struts based Java 6 application to Websphere 8.5 from a perfectly running application in Websphere 6.1. Have made no code changes as of now. But this one throws me off.I get Verify Error / stack Underflow error as below:

```
[7/16/15 17:03:20:443 EDT] 000000b1 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause UrlGateway: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY036 stack underflow&#59; class=com/ibm/ws/jsp/webcontainerext/AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper, method=createClassLoader&#40;&#41;V, pc=113
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:153)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:194)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1132)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
at com.mycompany.common.web.UrlSignedLaunchGateway.handleRequest(UrlGateway.java:71)
at com.mycompany.common.web.BaseServlet.doGet(BaseServlet.java:121)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:975)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY036 stack underflow; class=com/ibm/ws/jsp/webcontainerext/AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper, method=createClassLoader()V, pc=113
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:91)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.ws.WASJSPExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WASJSPExtensionProcessor.java:137)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:479)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.getServletWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:338)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:965)
... 33 more
```

At line #8 in above logs it points to the line#71 in my UrlGateway class which does nothing besides getting the parameters from the request and forwarding to index.jsp. Line #71 of my class is as below:

```
application.getRequestDispatcher(forwardPath).forward(request,response);//application is instance of ServletContext
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Is this due to potential bug in Websphere 8.5?
-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's or bug in WS 8.5 and you need to update, see here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM78020

Or it's code coverage issue and you need to disable it, like said here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21617205